# Get values from ResultSet without using next() method

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

There is a way to get the first row from ResultSet before calling next() method?
The code is something like:

```
String idElementPrev = /*here I would get the element*/
while (rs.hasNext()) {
    String idElement = rs.getInt("elementId");
    if (idElementPrev == idElement) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want ? You want to compare the first line with the second one ? So just read the first line outside the while loop (you need to move the cursor forward) then do the loop

Comment: Because I have multiple same value and I need to create a new object only if the idElement is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with condition, to solve your problem you can use a List, and you can use contains to check if the value exist or not in your list, here is an example  :

```
List<int> list = ...;
int idElement;
while (rs.next) {
    idElement = rs.getInt("elementId");
    if (list.contains(idElement)) {
       //do this
    }else{
       //do this
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the elements before. I think I should use next() to get first element and previous() to rewind the cursor. Then I can loop into rs.next()

Comment: @FedericoRampazzo just use a list and stock the first element in this list in the first iteration, in the second you can check with contains and so one